# Discuss the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1/2+(-1)^n}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Discuss the convergence of the  series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n}{n}$.

Attempt: Since the given series is alternating series, I am using Leibniz test.

The terms of the series are $\frac{-1}{2\cdot 1},\frac{3}{2\cdot 2},\frac{-1}{2\cdot 3},\frac{3}{2\cdot 4},\frac{-1}{2\cdot 5},\ldots$

That is equal to $\frac{1}{2}(-1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{-1}{3},\frac{3}{4},\frac{-1}{5},\ldots)$.

Hence $a_n= \frac{-1}{2n-1}$ if $n$ is odd and $a_n=\frac{3}{n}$ if $n$ is even.

$a_n$ goes to zero. But $a_n$ not decreasing. Hence the series divergent.This argument will work or not please help me!

Comment: Is this a homework problem? What have you tried?

Comment: No. Actually this is a NBHM problem. I was using lebinitz test but i did't get any conclusion.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

$$\frac{\frac12+(-1)^n}{n}=\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$

Comment: Ok. If i split the summation i will get one is convergent another one is divergent. can we say from that anything

Comment: The alternating sum on the right converges to -ln(2).  The sum on the left is 1/2 of the harmonic series, which diverges.  Since a part of the series diverges, the composite (i.e. original) series diverges.  Divergence trumps all. If any sub-part diverges, then the whole diverges.

Comment: We can say that is sum of the series is divergent.

Comment: @Murugan. If you have one sequence that diverges you cannot have one that converges if you add something to the one that diverges :-) this is intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at creating a sequence that consists of summing 2 subsequent terms of the original sequence.

$b_{n} = a_{2n+1} + a_{2n+2} = \frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{2n + 1} + \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{2n+ 2}
 = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2n+2} - \frac{1}{2n + 1}) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{(2n+1)-(2n+2)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}$

I'm not sure about the actual value but if I am correct the series of $b_n$ converges and therefor the series of $a_n$ converges.

Edit: Sorry, I made an error. My the series of my sequence $b_n$ as constructed above is convergent but is not the same as yours.

The correct one is:
$b_n = a_{2n+1} + a_{2n+2} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{2n+1} + \frac{\frac{3}{2}}{2n+2} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{4n+1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}$

Which is divergent.